# Prove that there is a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and for each $x \in [a,b]$, there is a $y \in [a,b]$ such that $|f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. Prove that there is a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$

I have no idea on how to start. This looks similar to Intermediate Value Theorem but after I look carefully, they are not similar. Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the minimum of $|f(x)|$?

Comment: @sos440:$f(x)=0$ ?

Comment: try to draw a counterexample, that's when the solution started to reveal itself for me. sos440's idea could conceivably come from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact, 
$$\inf_{x \in [a, b]}|f(x)| = |f(c)|$$
for some $c \in [a, b]$ by the extreme value theorem, and by assumption we can find $d \in [a, b]$ such that $|f(d)| \le \dfrac{1}{2}|f(c)| \le |f(c)|$.  It follows that $f(c) = 0$.

Comment: how we conclude $f(c)=0$ from the inequality?

Comment: @Idonknow If $f(c) \ne 0$, then $|f(c)| > 0$, but that would imply $|f(d)| < |f(c)|$, contradicting our assumption that $|f|$ attains its minimum at $c$.

Answer (score 2):

The approach in the comment by sos440, and in the answer by Brian, is by far the best. Here is a clumsy but natural approach that might suggest itself.

Let $a_0$ be a point in our interval. By the condition on $f$, there is an $a_1$ in our interval such that $|f(a_1)|\le \frac{1}{2}|f(a_0)|$. But then there is an $a_2$ in our interval such that $|f(a_2)|\le \frac{1}{2}|f(a_1)|$. And so on.

Now consider the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$. This has a convergent subsequence. Let that subsequence converge to $c$.

Since the $f(a_i)$ converge to $0$, and $f$ is continuous, it follows that $f(c)=0$

Comment: why we know that $f(a_i)$ converges to $0$?

Comment: Let $b=f(a_0)$. Then $|f(a_n)|\le \frac{b}{2^n}$ by the condition on $f$. For $|f(a_1)|\le b/2$, $|f(a_2)|\le |f(a_1)|/2\le b/4$, and so on.