# Show the following continuous function has a solution $f(c) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $S = [0,1] \times [0,1]$, and let $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Assume for each $a \in S$, there exists a $b \in S$ such that $|f(b)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$. Show that there exists a point $c \in S$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

My idea is to use the intermediate value theorem. So let $a \in S$. Then, there exists $b \in S$ such that $|f(b)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$.

If $f(a) = 0$ or $f(b) = 0$, then we're done. So assume $f(a) \neq 0$ and $f(b) \neq 0$.

Then, from $|f(b)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$, we have $-\frac{1}{2}|f(a)| \leq f(b) \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$.

But I don't see how I can apply IVT from here since we are not guaranteed that $\pm \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$ is in the range of $f$. Perhaps $f$ maps $S$ to only positive reals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f \in C [a,b]$ such that $\forall x\exists y$ such that $|f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. Prove that $\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643681/let-f-in-c-a-b-such-that-forall-x-exists-y-such-that-fy-leq-frac) – that is about a function on an (one dimensional) interval, but the proof is the same.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the intermediate value theorem here, because $f$ is defined on a subset of $\Bbb R^2$,

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3881742/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347911/42969.

Comment: Yeah I see my approach isn't very useful. But I planned on using the generalized intermediate value theorem involving connectedness

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $a_1\in S.$ (If $f(a_1)=0$ we are done. So assume $f(a_1)\ne 0.$) There exists $a_2\in S$ such that $|f(a_2)|\le \dfrac {|f(a_1)|}{2}.$ And there exists $a_3\in S$ such that $|f(a_3)|\le \dfrac {|f(a_2)|}{2}=\dfrac {|f(a_1)|}{2^2}.$

Use that $S$ is compact and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Fix ANY $a_0\in S$.

If $f(a_0)=0$, you are done.

Assume $|f(a_0)|>0$. for $a_0\in S$, there exists $a_1\in S$ such that $|f(a_1)|\le \frac{1}{2}|a_0|$.

For $a_1\in S$, there exissts $a_2\in S$ such that $|f(a_2)|\le \frac{1}{2}|f(a_1)|\le \frac{1}{2^2}|f(a_0)$.

So, by induction, you construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $|f(a_n)|\le\frac{1}{2^n}|f(a_0)|$. In particular, $f(a_n)\to 0$.

Since $S$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ of $(a_n)$ converging to some point $a\in S$.

Now, since $f$ is continuous, $f(a)=\lim_k f(a_{n_k})=0$.